# How to open word 5.0 files?

Tags: libreoffice, file-format, conversion, microsoft-word

I tried Libreoffice but failed.

I used the `file` command, but it only recognizes the file as "data".

Is there a way to open a very old format like a Word 5.0 file?

---

After I use `catdoc`,it shows this in vim:

[image: garbled text]

---

Trying to use dosbox to install Word:
[image: more garbled text]

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly there is Word 2 and Word 6 and nothing inbetween for Windows. Word 5 is Mac OS and from 1989. I am unsure if my anwer works for Mac files... it did work on a very very old Word file I was intriged by why I saved it ;)

Comment: So how to read word 5.0?

Comment: Are you sure this is a word 5.0 file and not a newer Word?

Comment: Very old word which version is 5.0. I have checked the first magic number. I also can't read it on office2007.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to wait for someone else to show up. Deleted answer cuz it was not correct ;)

Comment: Thank you for trying providing answers. Let me I learn more tools~ By the way, what is the sign ";)" means? Thank you~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install dosbox
- Download word55_en.exe from http://www.bttr-software.de/freesoft/txtedit1.htm (bottom the page)
- Run downloaded exe (from dosbox): unpack install files
- Run setup.exe (to install word55)
- Run word.exe
- Ready

Comment: I have installed word successfully, but it also couldn't read that doc file. It couldn't show any correct chinese words.

Comment: I have updated my origin post.

Comment: Try: http://www.docspal.com/

Comment: It says :Failed. Conversion could not be performed.